# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() wamp

Tags: php, wamp, sqlsrv

I have done all the following method below:

- reinstall my 64 bit WAMP into 32 bit
- downloaded SQLSRV30.EXE and pasted `php_sqlsrv_54_ts` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts` in ext
- added `extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` in php.ini
- installed MS SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver

Repeated those steps a few times and my phpinfo() still does not has the sqlsrv section. What should I do now?

Comment: This seems like an installation issue. SO isn't the place for such questions if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

I always perform installations trhought [Webplatform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Try it installation it's very easy.