# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\last\connect.php

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, server, sqlsrv

I am simply trying to connect my php to an microsoft sql server 2005. However, I'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\last\connect.php

My code is simply:

```
<?php
$serverName = "OurIPAddress"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Thenameofourdatabase", "UID"=>"OurID", "PWD"=>"Ourpassword");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

I installed microsoft driver 3.0 from this link [Microsoft driver 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)
and edited the php.ini file from the apache server with `extension=c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll.`

Following the instructions carefully the sqlsrverconnectdriver doesn't show on php_info()

P.S I followed this links:
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)    [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881636/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-wamp)    [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459658/call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-wamp-www-webs-client-php-on-li)

Comment: Apache restarted? Error.log? Guessing the right DLL version is too broad; and you didn't even specify which compilation parameters your PHP setup was built with.

Comment: 1. Apache was restarted several 

times.  2. I don't know how how check the 

error log.  3. System: WIndows 7 

Ultimate Edition.  Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)  Architecture (x64)  Thread safety: Enabled  extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll

Answer (score 1):

First, you must use a driver that match your PHP version and in your case is [Microsoft Drivers 3.1 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) for your PHP 5.5. Extract the `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`, or `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` to the `ext` folder, and set the `php.ini`.

Then install the [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

**Notice**: that the drivers only work for **WAMP 32 bit** and you can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b.exe/download), even if you use the 64 bit OS version.

I've try many time to use the driver on WAMP 64bit with no luck. If you still got the error, you can share the log in `c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log` here. Maybe I or someone else can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You should download Microsoft Drivers 3.1 for PHP for SQL Server if your PHP version is 5.5 or later.

However, version 3.1 requires SQL Server 2008 and later.

More information and download link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 0):

If You have this problem

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ocilogon()

You will go in the folder `C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4/bin/php.ini` and you will discomment `(;)` in the line extension which have oci.